# How do I add iOS 14 and 15 emojis to an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift app in XCode 13.2.1 that will run on iOS 13.0+. Apple added emojis to iOS 14 and others to iOS 15 that we would like to use for all users of iOS13 onward. Is there a way to get those emojis into our app so that when the app loads those emojis are available like other emojis, as if the app were running under iOS 15? That is, I don't want the added emoji's to be handled specially.

Comment: No, they are part of iOS itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emojis and SF Symbols can only be added via software update. All devices that support iOS 13 support iOS 15 and iOS has a very high adoption rate for this to be an issue. Back in June, iOS 14 was said to have an [apoption rate of 90%](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/06/04/ios-14-installation-rates-june-2021/) and recent numbers indicate that iOS 15 has an [adoption rate of at least 60%](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/12/09/ios-15-adoption-80-days-after-launch/)

## Solution

You could potentially add a toolbar above the keyboard and have `UIBarButtonItem` that could use images of the emojis you want as their foreground. Although, you can create IBActions for these and maybe link them to the unicode of the emoji, the emojis probably won't be displayed properly in textfields if the iOS version does not support it.

### Resources

[How to add a toolbar above the keyboard using inputAccessoryView](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-toolbar-above-the-keyboard-using-inputaccessoryview)

[UIBarbuttonItemDecleration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617163-init)